# How can i convert my app data into JSON object to send to server

Tags: android

Iam new to ANDROID. I want to send some data to server in JSON format. How can i convert my data mobilenumber, and message into JSON format in my java file. Then i want to send it through "https". How can i send??? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [simple-json library](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/) to encode your data into json-format